# Issue while integrating CDS with Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I had created angular app and did respective changes according to documentation below and able to load spartacus store.
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries/
trying to configure CDS on same app by following link below
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/cds-integration/
after running "npm i @spartacus/cds"
when i start app using "ng serve", there is an issue:
Error: ./src/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
TypeError: angularCompiler.getResourceDependencies is not a function or its return value is not iterable
at getDependencies (C:\corpgit_ccv2\DACommerceCloud2005-1\js-storefront\mystoreb2ctest\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:291:56)
at C:\corpgit_ccv2\DACommerceCloud2005-1\js-storefront\mystoreb2ctest\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:414:20
at analyzingFileEmitter (C:\corpgit_ccv2\DACommerceCloud2005-1\js-storefront\mystoreb2ctest\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:337:20)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
when i run "npm audit", there is a suggestion to upgrade angular CLI version to @angular/cli@11.2.4.
But as per first documentation, angular CLI version should be <11.
Please suggest.
I'm using SAP Commerce 2011.

Comment: Hi Team, any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

The angular version 11.2.4 should also work with other softwares that you have. Please upgrade and then let us know if the problem persists.

If not, then we will update the documentation.

Comment: Upgraded Angular CLI to 11.2.4, Please see below: Angular CLI: 11.2.4
Node: 12.18.3
Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1102.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         11.2.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   11.2.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          11.2.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.1102.4 (cli-only) , created new app and tried to install spartacus schematics, installation failed. error is:Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/config'

Comment: any suggesions?